# Show/Hide using drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I am trying to use this code below.  I like the code but I want the default to be DIV Area 1.  I have the HTML code showing DIV Area 1 in the drop down menu but I want the Javascript to show DIV AREA 1 by default. What would be the code?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.box').hide();
        $('#dropdown').change(function() {
            $('.box').hide();
            $('#div' + $('#dropdown').val()).show();
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
     <option value="0">Choose</option>
     <option value="area1" selected="selected">DIV Area 1</option>
     <option value="area2">DIV Area 2</option>
     <option value="area3">DIV Area 3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="divarea1" class="box">DIV Area 1</div>
<div id="divarea2" class="box">DIV Area 2</div>
<div id="divarea3" class="box">DIV Area 3</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.box').hide().first().show();
```

Or:

```
$('.box').hide().filter("#divarea1").show();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2RDyf/)

Put one of the above in the DOM ready event:

```
$(function(){ /*...*/ });
```

Or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* ... */ });
```

**Full code:** (It should answer you next question regarding  how to show the selected div...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.box').hide().filter("#divarea1").show();

    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        var selectedId= $(this).find(':selected').text().replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
        console.log(selectedId);
        $('.box').hide().filter('#' + selectedId).show();
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

could do this...

`$('.box').hide().filter(':first').show();`

Comment: I'm sure that `.filter(':first')` is a very very slow way of filtering. Think about the actions need to be done to know what `:first` is!

Comment: yeah yours is probably more efficient

Answer (score 0):

A lot of complicated answers for a simple problem:

`$('.box:gt(0)').hide();`

I'd code it up like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.box:gt(0)').hide();

    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        $('.box:visible').hide();
        if ($(this).prop('selectedIndex')>0)
            $('.box').eq($(this).prop('selectedIndex')-1).show();        
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/xNZWY/

If you remove the 1st option from your dropdown (since you are preselecting is it necessary?) it becomes a little simpler since we can remove the `if`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.box:gt(0)').hide();

    $('#dropdown').change(function() {
        $('.box:visible').hide();
        $('.box').eq($(this).prop('selectedIndex')-1).show();        
    });
});​
```